# gnuplot , non-numeric repeated x values

Tags: gnuplot

I have data set (filename 'data') like this:

```
a 10.1
b 10.1
c 10.2
b 15.56
a 3.20
```

and I would like to plot this data as points. When I try:

```
plot 'data' using 2:xticlabels(1)
```

I get plot with 5 x-axis values a,b,c,b,a but I wish to get only 3 (a,b,c (the order is not important)) on plot with all 5 y values. Is it possible?

My real data file looks like this:

```
2-8-16-17-18   962.623408
2-3-4-5-6      -97.527840
2-8-9-10-11    962.623408
2-8-9-10-11    937.101308
2-3-4-5-6       37.101308
```

and has about thousand records.

---

I don't know how to use mgilson's code, but he give me an idea. I add to data file additional column (index):

```
1 a 10.1 
2 b 10.1 
3 c 10.2 
2 b 15.56 
1 a 3.20
```

after which ploting in gnuplot is easy:

```
plot 'data' u 1:3
```

I use perl, so my script lookls like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
$index_number = 0; 
while (<>) 
{ 
   $line = $_;
   @columns = split(" ",$line);
   $col1 = $columns[0];
   $col2 = $columns[1];
   if( not exists $non_numeric{$col1} )
   {
      $index_number++;
      $non_numeric{$col1} = $index_number;
   }
   print "".$non_numeric{$col1}."\t".$col1."\t".$col2."\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Does the order on the x-axis actually matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that you can come up with a gnuplot only solution.  However, this *should* work as long as you have python2.5 or newer installed on your system.  (It works with your test data).

```
import sys
import collections

data = collections.defaultdict(list)
keys = []

# build a mapping which maps values to xticlabels (hereafter "keys")
# Keep a second keys list so we can figure out the order we put things into
# the mapping (dict)
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        key,value = line.split()
        data[key.strip()].append( value )
        keys.append(key.strip())

def unique(seq):
    """
    Simple function to make a sequence unique while preserving order.
    Returns a list
    """
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [ x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen_add(x) ]

keys = unique(keys) #make keys unique

#write the keys alongside 1 element from the corresponding list.
for k in keys:
    sys.stdout.write( '%s %s\n' % (k, data[k].pop()) )

# Two blank lines tells gnuplot the following is another dataset
sys.stdout.write('\n\n')

# Write the remaining data lists in order assigning x-values
# for each list (starting at 0 and incrementing every time we get
# a new key)
for i,k in enumerate(keys):
    v = data[k]
    for item in v:
       sys.stdout.write( '%d %s\n' % (i, item) )
```

Now the script to plot this:

```
set style line 1 lt 1 pt 1
plot '<python pythonscript.py data' i 0 u 2:xticlabels(1) ls 1,\
     '' i 1 u 1:2 ls 1 notitle
```

Here's how this works.  When you do something like `plot ... u 2:xticlabels(1)`, gnuplot *implicitly* assigns sequential integer x-values to the data points (starting at 0).  The python script re-arranges the data to make use of this fact.  Basically, I create a mapping which maps the "keys" in the first column to a list of elements that correspond to that key.  In other words, in your dummy datafile, the key `'a'` maps to the list of values `[10.1, 3.2]`.  However, python dictionaries (mappings) aren't ordered.  So I keep a second list which maintains the order  (so that you axes are labelled as 'a', 'b', 'c' instead of 'c','a','b' for instance).  I make sure that the axes list is unique so that I can use it to print the necessary data.  I write the data in 2 passes.  The first pass prints only one value from each list along with the mapping "key".  The second pass prints the rest of the values along with the x-value that gnuplot will implicitly assign to them.  Between the two datasets, I insert 2 blank lines so that gnuplot can sort out the difference using the `index` keyword (here abbreviated to `i`).  Now we just need to plot the two datasets accordingly.  First we set a linestyle so that both passes will have the same style when plotted.  Then we plot index 0 (the first dataset) with the xticlabels and index 1 using the x-value,y-value pairs the python script calculated (`u 1:2`).  Sorry the explanation is long (and that the original version was slightly buggy).  Good luck and happy gnuplotting!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records, there *is* a not too complicated *gnuplot-only* solution!
As the OP already wrote, it cannot simply be done by `plot FILE u 2:xtic(1)`.

The solution is a variation and mix of Christoph's answer to
[Gnuplot, plotting a graph with text on y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22995429/7295599) and my answer to [How do I group strings and their data using Gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15316764/7295599)

**How it works:**

- function `myX(col)`: while plotting the data row by row: if the string (of your x-column) is not yet found in the string variable `list`, append it surrounded by quotes, increase the counter `c` by 1 and add the value of `c` to the list as well, and return the index of the current string

At the end, the value of the string `list` in the example below will be:

```
"a" 1 "b" 2 "c" 3
```

- the function `index(list,s)` will return the index of `s` in `list` by matching the substring `s` (check `help strstrt`) and extracting the succeeding number.

**Data:** `SO12123578.dat`

```
a  10.1
b  10.1
c  10.2
b  15.56
a  3.20
```

**Script:** (works at least with gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### use string values as x-values
reset

FILE = "SO12123578.dat"

list = ''
c = 0
index(list,s) = (_n=strstrt(list,s)) ? int(word(list[_n+strlen(s):],1)) : 0
myX(col)      = (_s='"'.strcol(col).'"', strstrt(list, _s) ? '' : list=list.sprintf('%s %d ',_s,c=c+1), index(list,_s))

set offset 1,1,1,1

plot FILE u(myX(1)):2:xtic(1) w p pt 7 lc rgb "red" notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]