# Gnuplot, plotting a graph with text on y axis

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a list with values that looks like this:

```
directory  file_sizes
dir1         200
dir1         150
dir2         200
dir3          40
```

Ideally the y axis would have the text (first column) and the numbers (second column) on the x axis. I think a dots plotting would be best as I have a lot of dirs (20-30) and millions of files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually, you can place text on the y-axis with e.g. `plot 'file' using 2:0:ytic(1)`. But in your case you have `dir1` twice, what should happen in this case? And where do you have your files? In the example there is only the file size.

Comment: I think his best option would be to *assign* a number to each directory (dir1 = 1, dir2 = 2, etc) and then use `set ytics ("dir1" 1, "dir2" 2)`. A long set of `set ytics` label arguments could be generated with a short bash script, and then the input file would obviously need to be changed to containing numbers `1, 2, 3...` rather than directory names.

Comment: @Miguel Thats exactly what the `using ...:ytic(1)` part does automatically with the data from the file.

Comment: @Christoph: It is actually not the same in his case because he has repeated occurrences of "dir1". The way you propose will print one label per data entry. In the example, it would print "dir1" at y = 1 and then again "dir1" at y = 2. The way I propose would print "dir1" at 1 and then plot two data points at x = 200 and x = 150, both at y = 1.

Comment: @Miguel Hmm, quite right. I should think a bit before commenting :) Maybe the OP can tell us if thats, what he intended.

Comment: Come to think of it, it would be interesting if there was a feature in gnuplot that allowed recognition of repeated labels.

Comment: @Miguel No, gnuplot hasn't such a feature. But I took the challenge, see my answer. That is rather limited and dirty, but may work :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a rather dirty gnuplot script, which does the filtering of the directory names completely inside of gnuplot. I love dirty gnuplot tricks :)

Unfortunately this works only if the directory names don't contain white spaces. If a more sophisticated filtering is required, you must use an external tool for preprocessing.

Here we go:

The idea is to have a variable `list` which contains all directory names encountered so far, separated by spaces. For any row a function `add_dir` checks if the current name is already in the list and add it if not. For this to work properly, you must delimit your directory names stored in `list` with a token, which doesn't occur in a name itself, I choose `|`.

For plotting, a function `index` returns the position of the current directory in the `list` using the `words` builtin function (this is why directory names cannot have spaces inside):

```
list = ''
index(w) = words(substr(list, 0, strstrt(list, w)-1))
add_dir(d) = (strstrt(list, d) == 0 ? list=list.' '.d : '')

set offset 1,1,1,1
plot 'file.txt' using (d='|'.strcol(1).'|', add_dir(d), $2):(index(d)):ytic(1) with points notitle
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Nicely done. It's good you came up with a gnuplot-only solution.