# Is it possible to combine xticlabels with splot?

Tags: gnuplot, gnu, categorical-data

I have data like:

```
0 FRANCK -0.46
0 JUSSE -1.41
1 JUSSE -0.13
1 FRANCK -2.10
```

and I want to do a 3D plot, but I need to show the categories (or labels):

```
splot "map.gnu" using 1:2:3:yticlabels(2) with points palette pointsize 3 pointtype 7
```

This gives me an error:

```
 syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: My understanding is that with `splot` you will need to provide 4 columns: three columns of cartesian data and fourth for text labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also provide a column for the y-values. Gnuplot cannot autogenerate coordinates for the same strings. But with 4.6.4 I don't get an error if I test your code, it only tells me `warning: No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range. All points x value undefined`. If you provide a file with the format

```
0 0 FRANCK -0.46
0 1 JUSSE -1.41
1 1 JUSSE -0.13
1 0 FRANCK -2.10
```

and plot with

```
splot "map.gnu" u 1:2:4:yticlabels(3) w p palette ps 3 pt 7
```

if works fine with 4.6.4.

… did I say it doesn't work with your original file? Thats not completeley true ;)

```
list = ''
index(w) = words(substr(list, 0, strstrt(list, w)-1))
add_label(d) = (strstrt(list, d) == 0 ? list=list.' '.d : '')

splot 'map.gnu' using (d='|'.strcol(2).'|', add_label(d), $1):(index(d)):3:ytic(2) w p palette ps 3 pt 7
```

For an explanation, please see my answer to [Gnuplot, plotting a graph with text on y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23009322/2604213). Result with 4.6.4:

[image]

I've seen, that the alignment of the ytics cannot be controlled with `left` or `right`. You must use `offset` to correct the tic label position once you've defined your view angles.

Comment: Your index(w) version works perfectly for me - thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the easiest way to do it without changing your data file is by mapping `FRANCK`, `JUSSE`, etc. onto a numerical array that allows gnuplot to interpret those names as numbers. Ideally, you would define a function `map(x)` that takes the name as an argument and returns a number, for instance `map("FRANCK") = 0`, `map("JUSSE") = 1`, etc.:

```
map(x) = x eq "FRANCK" ? 0 \
: x eq "JUSSE" ? 1 : 1/0 # You can add more names
splot "map.gnu" u 1:(var = strcol(2), map(var)):3:yticlabels(2) \
with points palette pointsize 3 pointtype 7
```

[image]

Of course Christoph's answer is more handy if you don't know beforehand how many and which names are present on the file.