# gnuplot: Stacking data by a string value

Tags: gnuplot

I have this input file (it is automatically generated):

```
"John";"580"
"Monica";"580"
"Monica";"580"
"John";"580"
"John";"580"
"John";"580"
"John";"580"
"Mark";"576"
"Monica";"580"
"John";"580"
"John";"580"
"Mark";"586"
"John";"580"
"John";"580"
"John";"580"
"John";"580"
"Monica";"580"
```

And I want to create a chart with the sum of the second column number per person.

I tried different possible solutions to no avail. For example:

```
set datafile separator ";"    
plot "input.csv" u  1:2:xtic(1) smooth cumulative w boxes
```

This returns an error, I understand gnuplot is expecting a numerical value and not a string, so how can I do this?

I can't add any other column to the file as it is generated automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bit tricky. Basically you must assign each string a unique number which you use to add the values belonging to the same strings:

```
list = ''
index(w) = words(substr(list, 0, strstrt(list, w)-1))
add_label(d) = (strstrt(list, d) == 0 ? list=list.' '.d : '')

set datafile separator ";"    

plot 'input.csv' using (d='|'.strcol(1).'|', add_label(d),index(d)):2:xtic(1) smooth frequency w boxes
```

Note, that you must use `smooth frequency` to sum up all values belonging to a single string, `cumulative` would sum up *all* values.

My proposed solution works only for strings without spaces (no matter if they're in quotes or not), but might be extended to work also with spaces (could become a bit lengthy).

You'll find a more detailled description in a previous answer [Gnuplot, plotting a graph with text on y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22995429/2604213).

Comment: Wow, you nailed it. Thank you!! And yes, you are right about the smooth parameter, thanks man.

Comment: extra question: do you know why this doesn't work if I use `set logscale y`?

Comment: No, at the moment I don't know why this doesn't work. I'll see if I can track this down.