# gnuplot timeseries with categorical states as step function

Tags: gnuplot, time-series, categorical-data

I have a datafile which looks something like this:

```
0;State a
1;State a
2;State b
3:State b
4:State a
```

Where the first column represents the time in seconds, and the second column represents a certain state.

I want to plot the occurences of the events in gnuplot over time. I am trying to use the following for plotting:

```
set datafile separator ";"
plot 'data' using 1:2:yticlabels(2)
```

However I get the following error:

```
warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
                                       ^
x range is invalid
```

It seems like gnuplot won't recognize the strings as categorical values. The result should look something like a non-continous step function:

```
       ^
State b┼       ┌───────┐
       │       │       │
State a┼───────┘       └────
       │
       ┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼─>
       0   1   2   3   4   5
```

Is this sort of plot possible with gnuplot? If, so how would you do this?

Comment: Do you have a known number of states and do you know the state names? Or is this dynamical?

Comment: I have different files containing different states. Most of the time these are binary "on/off" or "active/inactive". It would be great to have a general solution for this because the names depend on the file that is loaded and there are some files with more states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, gnuplot doesn't recognize strings as categorical values. You must do those assignments "string → integer" yourself.

The easiest way to do this mapping is to use an external tool like `awk` and add the integer values on-the-fly. The following `awk` call does this mapping and adds the values to the output:

```
awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' '{
  if (!($2 in array)) { 
    array[$2] = length(array)
  }
  print $1,$2,array[$2]
}' data.csv
```

Using the gnuplot syntax

```
plot "< awk ..."
```

you can combine the `awk` call directly with the plotting:

```
set datafile separator ";"
set offset 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1
set xtics 0,1
plot "< awk -F ';' -v OFS=';' '{if (!($2 in array)) { array[$2] = length(array) }; print $1,$2,array[$2]}' data.csv" using 1:3:ytic(2) w step lw 3 notitle
```

The output is

[image]

Alternatively, if you haven't access to `awk`, you can do the preprocessing also using e.g. a python script like the following `cat.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
a={}
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.strip().split(';')
        if (not fields[1] in a):
            a[fields[1]] = len(a)
        print("{0};{1};{2}".format(fields[0], fields[1], a[fields[1]]), file=sys.stdout)
```

and call it with

```
plot "< python cat.py data.csv" ...
```

Side note: maybe one could also do this using gnuplot only, but that can become quite ugly, see [Gnuplot, plotting a graph with text on y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23009322/2604213) for a similar use case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a (historical) reason why gnuplot does not provide this functionality. It seems to be an important task for data exploration?

Comment: The main reason is, that gnuplot doesn't want to become a full-featured data processing tool. It's main focus is on plotting data, not processing them. So this kind of tasks are outsourced to other tools, which are more appropriate. This is also the reason why gnuplot doesn't have an array data structure.

Comment: Sounds reasonable and in accordance with the unix philosophy. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

As there are only two states, I wouldn't say this qualifies for the *gnuplot is not a data processing tool* verdict (while that statement is generally true!).

This here should fit the bill:

```
f(s) = s eq "state a" ? 0 : s eq "state b" ? 1 : NaN
set dataf sep ";"
plot dataf using 1:(f(stringcolumn(2))) with steps # or fsteps
```

If you have a dozen different states, that's another story.

Explanation: You need the `stringcolumn()` function, because `column(2)` or `$2` return a fp number, or an error if they don't find something they can convert to a number.
The `=` operator only compares numeric values, you have to use `eq`.
And a?B:C is the `ternary operator`, returns C if A == 0, otherwise B.

Comment: In the comments @jdog says, that there can appear more than two states, which led me to the comment that you quote. And those states can differ between files.